# reading excel via linq, how to cast columns

Tags: c#, linq

I am reading an excel file and getting "specified cast is invalid"
What I notice is the ID and ParentID column from excel have decimals for instance 1235 is coming as 1235.0 , I believe this is causing the issue. I have tried to cast but not successful.

```
var ds = new DataSet();

        adapter.Fill(ds, "ErrorCodesExcel");

        System.Data.DataTable data = ds.Tables["ErrorCodesExcel"];
        var dataParsed = ds.Tables["ErrorCodesExcel"].AsEnumerable();


  var query = dataParsed.Select(x =>
                new ErrorCode
                {

           ID = x.Field<int>("ID"),
           ErrorDescription = x.Field<string>("ErrorDescription"),
           ErrorDescriptionWithParent = x.Field<string>("ErrorDescriptionWithParent"),
            ParentID = x.Field<int>("ParentID"),

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Excel, cell values are either `string` or `double`, and the `DataReader` won't do the cast for you, so you'll have to read from the reader as `double` and convert to an `int` (casting is one way):

```
ID = (int)x.Field<double>("ID"),
ErrorDescription = x.Field<string>("ErrorDescription"),
ErrorDescriptionWithParent = x.Field<string>("ErrorDescriptionWithParent"),
ParentID = (int)x.Field<double>("ParentID"),
```